# Replacement for Google Checkout XML API

Tags: android, google-play, google-checkout, sales-analytics

The retirement notice for Google Checkout at https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449?hl=en says:

> If you are a user of [Google Play or Google Wallet for digital goods],
>   but use the Google Checkout
>   APIs for notifications or reporting, stay tuned. **We will be announcing
>   replacement APIs shortly** and recommend you stop using the Checkout
>   APIs as soon as possible.

I am a user of Google Play, and I'm using the Google Checkout API for reporting. The said announcement was published back in May; was there any replacement API announced so far, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. There is not yet a replacement for the Checkout reporting API. I assume by "shortly", they mean it'll be ready in [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

I have to assume they will have something ready before the November 20th kill-date.

Comment: I'm selling digital goods on Google Play *and* using the Checkout XML API to integrate my sales data. The publishers' console already calls itself "Google Wallet". The old Checkout API still works. After Nov 20, it probably won't. So yes, I **will** be affected.

Comment: Hardly good news, but at least it's Google stringing me up, as opposed to me not finding the right announcement. If/when there is an replacement API and someone posts a link here, I'm gonna accept that answer instead :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Purchase Status API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html?utm_source=wallet-checkout&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=androidapi&utm_term=aug062013) looks promising.

For the list of sales, though, they recommend downloading sales reports. This does not sound promising at all - these are not realtime, like the old order list API was.

EDIT: Purchase status API sucks. It's not an order details retrieval the way Checkout API used to have - it's a basic "yes, an order took place" type of call. No amount, no customer data... Not a replacement for the Checkout API at all. I've filed a support ticket.